# devexpressRichedit localization does not take effect

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue to build a rich text project and want to implement localization, but it still does not take effect after loading the language pack file. Detailed operations are as follows:

```
npm i devextreme devextreme-dist devexpress-richedit --save
```

```
//main.js
import "../node_modules/devextreme-dist/css/dx.light.css";
import "../node_modules/devexpress-richedit/dist/dx.richedit.css";
```

Configure localization according to documentation：https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNetCore/401323/rich-edit/localization
The difference from the steps in the document is that I loaded the language pack in main.js and set the language.

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import "../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
import "../node_modules/devextreme-dist/css/dx.light.css"
import "../node_modules/devextreme-dist/js/dx.all.js"
import "../node_modules/devexpress-richedit/localization/dx-rich.zh-CN.js"
import "../node_modules/devexpress-richedit/dist/dx.richedit.css"
import "../node_modules/devexpress-richedit/dist/dx.richedit.js"
DevExpress.localization.locale("zh-CN")
import App from './App.vue'
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I haven't found any relevant information, I hope someone can give me an answer